# idl radius of each pixel

Tags: astronomy, idl-programming-language

I'm completely new to coding and have almost no idea what I'm doing. Currently I'm trying to find the radius of each pixel from the center of a galaxy in a fits file. I was told to try this by creating a blank array the same size as the fits file and I'm trying to use a for loop for each x value and another for each y.  So far, I have the array and have attempted to create the for loops.

```
xcenter =249.8
ycenter =250.0

d=fltarr(500,500)

for i=0,499 do begin
    d=d(i-xcenter,*)
endfor

for j=0,499 do begin
    d=d(j-ycenter,*)
endfor
```

I know this look awful and I obviously have no idea what I'm doing. So if anyone can offer any help at all I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at a simpler version first. Suppose you have 10 points on a line, and you want to calculate the distance of each point from some `xref`. IDL supports vector math, so you can do this:

```
xref = 5.4
x = dindgen(10)
distance = abs(x - xref)
```

I have used the [DINDGEN](http://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/DINDGEN.html) command here, and you can look up the help. Now in a 2d case, you want 2-d arrays: one will be a 500 * 500 array containing the X coordinate of each pixel, the other containing the Y coordinate. So the arrays will have to be of the form,

```
0 1 2 3 ...
0 1 2 3 ...
0 1 2 3 ...
```

and

```
0 0 0 0 ...
1 1 1 1 ...
2 2 2 2 ...
```

We can generate them using the `#` operator. Note that IDL counts from 0 by default.

```
just_one = replicate(1d, 500) ; contains 1 1 1 1 ...
one_500 = dindgen(500)        ; contains 0.0 1.0 2.0 ...
x = just_one # one_500
y = one_500 # just_one
```

Now you can calculate the distance as usual, d = sqrt(x*x + y*y), but using vector math again:

```
distance = sqrt( (x - xref) ^ 2 + (y - yref) ^ 2 )
```

This is a 500x500 array, which contains the distance of each pixel from your xref, yref points.

Comment: Thank you! This helped so much!